# Duplicates in ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am using AngularJS version `1.4.7` and have simple AngularJS controller which contains array of objects. I would like to display these objects as options in select by `ngOptions`.

The problem is that every object is duplicate and I don't know why. This duplicate is presented in the select only, the source object looks fine.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

function DemoCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.demoOptions = [
    {value: 1, label: 'Demo 1'},
    {value: 2, label: 'Demo 2'},
    {value: 3, label: 'Demo 3'}
  ];
  vm.selected = null;;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in vm.demoOptions track by item.value" ng-model="vm.selected">
    <option value="" selected ng-if="vm.selected === null">-- select --</option>
  </select>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected !== null">Selected item: <code>{{vm.selected}}</code></p>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected === null">No item is selected.</p>
  <pre>vm.demoOptions == {{vm.demoOptions|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Is it a bug? How can I remove duplicates without using a filter?

Note: This problem has occurred after update AngularJS from version `1.3.19` to `1.4.7`. I read the changelog but it tells only about addition of `track by` - I added it but with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known bug for 1.4.x before 1.4.8 you can check [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12190).

If you have to use angularjs 1.4.7 version then you can use `ng-show` instead `ng-if`

You can find changelog and error from [angularjs github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.x/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I made Google searches only with varieties of keyword duplicates.

Comment: acctually you don't need ng-show/ng-if in option :  https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ja217g5v/2/ (1.4.7)

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi the OP would have the `-- select --` disappeared as soon as you selected something. therefor you have to use ng-if or remove the option in version 1.4.7

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your `<option>` tag from the `<select>` field. Since everything inside it will be used for every item and the `<option>` tag itself is generated through the directive of angularJS.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

function DemoCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.demoOptions = [
    {value: 1, label: 'Demo 1'},
    {value: 2, label: 'Demo 2'},
    {value: 3, label: 'Demo 3'}
  ];
  vm.selected = null;;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in vm.demoOptions track by item.value" ng-model="vm.selected" ng-change="vm.setSelected()">
  </select>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected !== null">Selected item: <code>{{vm.selected}}</code></p>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected === null">No item is selected.</p>
  <pre>vm.demoOptions == {{vm.demoOptions|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: `you have to remove your <option> tag from the select field. since everything inside it will be used for every item.` are you sure ?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller it shouldn't related with it as I almost use ng-options with non-value 'Please Select' option...

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi In your Fiddle there is AngularJS version 1.4.8. So is it a bug in version 1.4.7?

Comment: in my office i am using angularjs 1.3 .. there is also working fine @Akarienta

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Sure sure I know. As I have written it worked well with version `1.3.19` but now I have to use version `1.4.7`.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi you are right when you update it to 1.4.8 it is working,,,

Comment: @charlietfl please tell me, why it's working then and the OPs question not? if it's a bug in 1.4.7 where you have to remove the option, that this kind of requirement is working, the answer itself is not incorrect. maybe the answer is just not complete.

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

function DemoCtrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.demoOptions = [
    {value: null, label: '--select--'},
    {value: 1, label: 'Demo 1'},
    {value: 2, label: 'Demo 2'},
    {value: 3, label: 'Demo 3'}
  ];
  vm.selected = vm.demoOptions[0];
  $scope.$watch(function(){ return vm.selected}, function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(!oldVal.value && newVal.value) {
     vm.demoOptions.shift();
    }
  });
  vm.setSelected = function(){
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="item.label for item in vm.demoOptions" ng-model="vm.selected" ng-change="vm.setSelected()">
    
  </select>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected !== null">Selected item: <code>{{vm.selected}}</code></p>
  <p ng-if="vm.selected === null">No item is selected.</p>
  <pre>vm.demoOptions == {{vm.demoOptions|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution but I would like to hide the empty option when user select something.

Comment: It still doesn't have the requested effect.

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake. now you can check

Comment: I think, using this solution, you don't have any problems with angular versions

Comment: welcome, and thank you , because these question/discussion will helps to others who are using different angular versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this in 1.4.8 or greater the reason may be [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4203). Duplicates can be created when using `$compile`. There are some workarounds on the bug page.